# Unity - Moving the player or the scenario - Endless runner

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, precision

I'm going to create an endless runner in Unity and I was wondering if I should move the player or the scenario during the runs.

The most obvious answer sounds like "the player" because you are moving fewer objects but... does the performance get affected if the size of the scenes is too large? I don't think so but my real worry is about the coordinate:

What happens if the player runs so far away that the coordinates can't fit in a float variable? I think that the transform component uses a Vector3 to store the coordinates and this Vector3 uses float variables (with a limit of +3.4E+38) for each of the coordinates.

Thank you for your answers in advance, 
Guillem Poy

Comment: I moved the player in my endless runner games, because it would take a very large amount of time to get to those high problematic values

Comment: One way around this is to start generating map pieces that bring you closer to 0,0 if you find that you are getting too far in a single direction - but in reality I don't think this is a problem you need to worry about.

Comment: Lestat I think that you are right, Even if the player is moving 1000 units per second, to achieve that problem, the player should be playing during 9.4+E32 hours (2.5+E29 years). I think that nobody is going to play this much ^^'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I don't know what happens if the value of the coordenates exceeds the capacity of a float variable (I think that then the number simply will be wrong) doing some calculus...

Even if the player is moving 1000 units per second, to create that problem, the player should be playing during 9.4+E32 hours (2.5+E29 years). I think that nobody is going to play this much.

So, the best option I think that is to move the player.